# Append value from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am begginner with Jquery/javascript.I was trying to take the value of textarea to append a div .But when i do this with jquery  it appends (i suppose) but only shows variable name.Why it happens?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/mburakerman/pen/yNdYYB)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#textbox').click(function(event) {
  if(event.which=13) {
    if($('#enter').prop("checked")) {

      $('#textbox').val('');
      event.preventDefault();

    }  
  }
  $('#send').click(function() {

    var userMessage = $('#textbox').val();
    $('#textbox').val('');
    $('#container').append("userMessage");

  });
 
 });
});
```

```css
* {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
  }
  body {
   background:#eee;
  }
 #container {
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
 }
 #controls {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:600px;
}
 #textbox {
  resize:none;
  width:540px;
  }
 #send {
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position:absolute;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="controls">
<textarea id="textbox" placeholder="Enter your message here!"></textarea>
<button id="send">Send</button><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="enter"><br>
<label for="enter">Send on enter</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#textbox').keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which==13 && $('#enter').prop("checked")==true) {
      $('#container').append("<br/>"+$('#textbox').val());
      $('#textbox').val('');
      event.preventDefault();
     }
  });

  $('#send').click(function() {
     var userMessage = $('#textbox').val();
     $('#textbox').val('');
     $('#container').append("<br/>"+userMessage);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks dude.Now my headache is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Close - no quotes around `userMessage`, so instead of Instead of `append("userMessage")` use:

```
$('#container').append(userMessage);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqZGrm

Comment: Thanks i also did like you do on sublime and checked on chrome it happened like this ? > http://i.imgur.com/FKDIEL1.png

Comment: Open the codepen I provided - do you still see that issue? It seems the css is off in your image.

Comment: I just have that issue on sublime but the code below solved the issuse.